# Edit template layout in Magento

Tags: magento

I'm trying to edit the right sidebar of the homepage of a site based on Magento. When I edit the `Layout Update XML` field in the `Custom design` part of the homepage, I see this code:

```
<reference name="right">
  <action method="unsetChild"><name>catalog.compare.sidebar</name></action>
  <action method="unsetChild"><name>right.newsletter</name></action>
  <action method="unsetChild"><name>cart_sidebar</name></action>
  <block type="catalog/product_new" name="home.catalog.product.new" alias="product_new" template="catalog/product/new.phtml" after="cms_page"/>
</reference>
```

But I can't find where would be the layout specified in the block tag. When I remove the whole code, the sidebar is still displaying but with the Compare Sidebar Widet on top of the rest of teh sidebar.

I'm new to Magento and a little bit lost. Thank for your help.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I need to change the static blocks that consist the sidebar. I can edit the static blocks separaterly, but I need to remove some block of the sidebar completely.

Comment: use `<remove name="block_name"/>` node inside of your `<reference name="right"/>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this

```
<remove name="catalog.compare.sidebar"/>
```

in `default`

like this

```
<default>
  <reference name="right">
      <remove name="catalog.compare.sidebar"/>
   </reference>

</default>
```

it will work

Comment: please check the compare side bar is present in catalog.xml and page.xml . Please use <remove> there also

Answer (score 0):

The best way to accomplish is to create local.xml file under your themes layout section and paste this code. So you do not need to search in all the files.

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <!-- remove compare sidebar -->
        <remove name="catalog.compare.sidebar"/>
    </default>
</layout>
```